# Yii wrong detect mimType

Tags: php, yii, upload, mime-types

I have an application in yii 1.1 and in CActiveRecord model a rule for checking uploaded file's mimType

```
'mimeTypes'=>'jpg,jpeg,gif,png'
```

But when I upload a jpg file it give me the error :

```
the file "picture003.jpg" cannot be uploaded. Only files of these MIME-types are allowed: jpg, jpeg, gif, png.
```

also i tried this :

```
'mimeTypes'=>'image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png'
```

and some time i get this error :

```
finfo_file(C:\xampp\tmp\phpD670.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct `'mimeTypes'=>'image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png'`, so to prevent next error

```
finfo_file(C:\xampp\tmp\phpD670.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Use file save after model save, cuase file will be deleted from temporrary dir after save.

```
if ( $model->save() ) {
   $model->image->saveAs(/*path*/);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @size ! You are right I should save file after save model but why ?? Can you explain about this and temporary directory please ?!

Comment: The files uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism and stored in temporary directory defined with `upload_tmp_dir` setting in `php.ini`. In this directory file "lives" while PHP script runing or script move it somewhere.